# What is the probability that the 5th letter received incorrectly will be the 71st letter in the message?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Full question:** A spy transmits a message to her contact one letter at a time; the probability that any given letter will be received incorrectly is 0.4, and the correctness of each letter's receipt is independent from that of each other letter's. What is the probability that the 5th letter received incorrectly will be the 71st letter in the message?

**Work so far:** 71 letters so n=71, 5 incorrect letters so x=5, probability that a letter is incorrect P=0.4:

Probability 5th incorrect letter is 71st letter: $\frac{[(71C5)\cdot(0.4)^5\cdot(0.96)^{66}]}{71}$

I am unsure if what I did is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, the probability you wrote is the probability that within the first 71 letters transmitted, exactly five are incorrectly transmitted and 66 are correctly transmitted **in any order**.  You applied the formula for the binomial distribution correctly except for an unnecessary division by 71, but this is the wrong problem.  You did not account for the stipulation that the 71st letter specifically must be one of the five incorrectly transmitted letters.

To continue, notice that for the 71st letter to be the fifth incorrectly transmitted letter the following two things must be true:

- Within the first 70 letters, exactly four are transmitted incorrectly and 66 correctly in any order
- The 71st letter is transmitted incorrectly.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: So, in that case, there is only 1 way of transmitting incorrectly the 71st letter with a 0.4 probability. Then it would be ((70C4)⋅(0.4)^4⋅(0.96)^66 + 0.4)/71?

Comment: @GabrielBello You incorrectly used a + instead of a $\times$, and why are you dividing by $71$?  I honestly hadn't noticed that you did that in the original answer too, but it shouldn't be there.

Comment: True. I forgot I was already using the probability for incorrect/correct (i.e. 0.4 or 0.96).

Comment: @GabrielBello thats another thing that I didn't notice you did originally.  What is $0.4+0.96$?  Is it equal to $1$?  No?  Then what needs to be fixed about that.  Notice that $0.4$ is not the same thing as $0.04$.

Comment: Yes of course, I was a bit sloppy while typing. I meant 0.04 and 0.96.

Comment: **EDIT** 0.4 is correctly since that's what's specified by the problem. For a correct letter the probability should be 0.6